# Give admin rights to specified directory and services

Tags: windows, services

Enviroment is:Windows SBS2011, Windows 7 as RDP gateway..

We'r using a 3dh part software. Somethimes we need to give admin rights to the vendor, 'coz need to update / configure the software.

This software use three services, and one directory for the data.

Is it possible to give admin rights to a user (stop, start service), but only for specified services?!

Thank you

HOlian

Comment: Did you managed to get this done?